# awaiting a Future versus Event.wait()

Tags: python, python-asyncio

In the [UDP client example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#asyncio-udp-echo-client-protocol) in the Python docs, they use `loop.create_future()` to create a new `Future`. The main program `await`s this future until result is set on it, at which point the program cleans up resources and terminates.

However, I have always used an `asyncio.Event` for this kind of thing.

Is there any difference between these two techniques? Is there any reason to prefer the Future instead of the Event?

```py
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
future = loop.create_future()
await future

event = asyncio.Event()
await event.wait()
```

Comment: read the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_future https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future

Comment: @AhmedAEK I am aware of what a `Future` is. I am asking about this specific usage of it, which seems equivalent to `Event.wait`.

Comment: They can be both used for synchronization, but a Future has a proper result and can raise exceptions. So, Event provides less features, but when the use case is only synchronization, it may express the intent better and be less error-prone. In fact, an event is implemented as a list of futures.

Comment: @user15681262 post that as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can be both used for synchronization, but a Future has a proper result and can raise exceptions.

So, Event provides less features, but when the use case is only synchronization, it may express the intent better and be less error-prone. In fact, an Event [is implemented](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8feb7ab77c80968a6de6079299a39b0494b1701b/Lib/asyncio/locks.py#L199) as a list of futures.

Comment: "Event provides less features" is a bit misleading, as a future is one-shot, whereas an Event can be used many times. One could say Event provides _different_ features, with some overlap.